# Django. Rest framework. How to add object ID in XML?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In DRF, I create XML in which I need to assign the object id to the main tag
It should look as follows:

```
<offer internal-id="Object ID">
    <type></type>
    <category></category>
    <url></url>
</offer>
```

I have a problem with the `offer tag` as I don’t know how to insert the object ID into it.
Nested tags are generated perfectly, there are no problems with them.
Here is my `views.py`:

```
class ZemlaXMLRenderer(XMLRenderer):
    root_tag_name = 'feed'
    item_tag_name = 'offer'

    def _to_xml(self, xml, data):
        if isinstance(data, (list, tuple)):
            for item in data:
                xml.startElement(self.item_tag_name, {'internal-id': 'Object ID'})
                self._to_xml(xml, item)
                xml.endElement(self.item_tag_name)
        super()._to_xml(xml, data)
```

Ideally, the output should be the following structure:

```
<offer internal-id="1">
    <type></type>
    <category></category>
    <url></url>
</offer>
<offer internal-id="2">
    <type></type>
    <category></category>
    <url></url>
</offer>
```

Thank!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my question. It turned out very simple:

```
class ZemlaXMLRenderer(XMLRenderer):
    root_tag_name = 'feed'
    item_tag_name = 'offer'

    def _to_xml(self, xml, data):
        if isinstance(data, (list, tuple)):
            for item in data:
                xml.startElement(self.item_tag_name, {'internal-id': str(item['id'])})
                self._to_xml(xml, item)
                xml.endElement(self.item_tag_name)
        super()._to_xml(xml, data)
```

After `internal-id`, I added `str(item ['id'])`.
Now each `offer` tag has its own `id`